# Limit not working, Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, database

The query works fine while having a few data, But in huge data Query is not working and gives error '#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query'.

I'm developing software in which I need to join many tables from the database. The query works fine while having a few data, now I have a huge amount of data at this stage Query is not working. In fewer data without limit, the query was working fine but with too many data I tried limit but it didn't work.
I increased the execution, and the query runs for ~119 sec. I want a faster result because it is not preferable to increase execution time in the server.

The query is given below.

```
SELECT
    `TA`.`id` AS `taid`,
    `T`.`id` AS `trip_id`,
    `TA`.`id` AS `adv_id`,
    `VO`.`id` AS `VO_id`,
    `P`.`id` AS `p_id`,
    `V`.`id` AS `v_id`,
    `J`.`id` AS `job_id`,
    `T`.`lr_date` AS `date`,
    `T`.`lr_no`,
    `J`.`movement_nature`,
    `J`.`material`,
    `J`.`job_no`,
    `V`.`vehicle_code`,
    `T`.`container1`,
    `T`.`container2`,
    `T`.`cont_size`,
    `T`.`from_id`,
    `T`.`total_freight`,
    `J`.`freight`,
    SUM(TA.amount) AS amount,
    SUM(TA.card) AS card,
    SUM(TA.add_card) AS add_card,
    `TA`.`rate` AS `rate`,
    SUM(TA.add_amount) AS add_amount,
    SUM(TA.party_advance) AS party_advance,
    SUM(TA.total_qty) AS fuel_amt,
    `VO`.`voucher_no`,
    `P`.`name` AS `party`,
    `O`.`name` AS `owner`,
    `R`.`frm`,
    `R`.`too`,
    `T`.`user` AS `trip_user`,
    `TA`.`user` AS `trip_adv_user`,
    `VO`.`user` AS `v_user`,
    `J`.`bill_no`,
    `D`.`name` AS `driver_name`,
    `TA`.`adv_type` AS `adv_type`,
    `TA`.`repair`,
    `T`.`status`,
    `J`.`job_nature`,
    `T`.`pc_packages`
FROM
    `job` `J`
LEFT JOIN `trip_log` `T` ON
    `T`.`job_id` = `J`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `trip_advance` `TA` ON
    `TA`.`trip_id` = `T`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `voucher` `VO` ON
    `VO`.`trip_adv_id` = `TA`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `vehicle` `V` ON
    `V`.`id` = `T`.`vehicle_id`
LEFT JOIN `parties` `P` ON
    `P`.`id` = `T`.`party`
LEFT JOIN `parties` `O` ON
    `O`.`id` = `V`.`owner_code`
LEFT JOIN `route` `R` ON
    `R`.`id` = `T`.`from_id`
LEFT JOIN `driver` `D` ON
    `D`.`id` = `T`.`driver_id`
WHERE
    `T`.`lr_date` >= "2019-04-15" AND `T`.`lr_date` <= "2019-04-30"
GROUP BY
    `T`.`id` limit 10;
```

I expect a much faster result without increasing the execution time.

Comment: Limit is working ok. The problem is that your query is taking too long to get those 10 first rows. Do you have indexes in all your id columns (for the ON part of the JOINS)?? Your GROUP BY will not work unless you have desactivated the ONLY FULL GROUP BY

Comment: I have no indexes in columns, grouping works fine as already set ONLY FULL GROUP BY. @nacho

Comment: I have just created an index for tables using "CREATE INDEX [index name] ON [table name]([column name]);", What next I have to do? @nacho

Comment: You need to create an index on trip_log.lr_date too, and then try again to see how much time it takes. You can do EXPLAIN before the SELECT to see how looks the execution plan

Comment: I tried it but not worked for me, can you pls write the query for me. @nacho

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT    `TA`.`id` AS `taid`,    `T`.`id` AS `trip_id`,    `TA`.`id` AS `adv_, and all the rest of your query ...

Comment: That I did, I was talking about select with indexes. @nacho

Comment: For the select you don't need to do anything. The system will detect the indexes and use them automatically